# How to serialize inner case objects with akka custom serialization?

Tags: scala, serialization, akka

I have a trait and case objects implementing it

```
trait Cowboy {
  def code: String
}

object Cowboy {
  case object Good extends Cowboy {
    val code = "G"
  }
  case object Bad extends Cowboy {
    val code = "B"
  }

  case object Ugly extends Cowboy {
    val code = "U"
  }

  def fromString(code: String) = code match {
    case Good.code => Good
    case Bad.code => Bad
    case Ugly.code => Ugly
  }
}
```

I want to be able to serialize them. With the following serialization configs

```
serializers {
  cowboySerializer = "mypackage.CowboySerializer"
}

serialization-bindings {
  "mypackage.Cowboy" = cowboySerializer
}
```

I get this warning:

> Multiple serializers found for class mypackage.Cowboy$Ugly$, choosing
>   first: Vector((interface
>   java.io.Serializable,akka.serialization.JavaSerializer@3fee36d8),
>   (interface
>   mypackage.Cowboy,brigadier.scraper.ScrapeStatusSerializer@10442350))

which means that java serializer is picked instead of mine.

If I disable java serializer via

```
akka.actor.serialization-bindings {
  "java.io.Serializable" = none
}
```

the following error occurs:

> Rejected to persist event type [mypackage.Cowboy$Ugly$] with sequence
>   number [1](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/serialization.html#Configuration) for persistenceId [XXX] due to [mypackage.Cowboy$Ugly$
>   cannot be cast to mypackage.Cowboy]

This seems strange for me because casting

```
Cowboy.Ugly.asInstanceOf[Cowboy]
```

obviously works.

I also tried to map every case object to serializer as [Akka docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/serialization.html#Configuration) says

> If your messages are contained inside of a Scala object, then in order
>   to reference those messages, you will need use the fully qualified
>   Java class name. For a message named Message contained inside the
>   object named Wrapper you would need to reference it as Wrapper$Message
>   instead of Wrapper.Message.

```
serialization-bindings {
  "mypackage.Cowboy$Good" = cowboySerializer
  "mypackage.Cowboy$Bad" = cowboySerializer
  "mypackage.Cowboy$Ugly" = cowboySerializer
}
```

and got ActorInitializationException caused by InvocationTargetException caused by ClassNotFoundException (can't find mypackage.Cowboy$Ugly class).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try changing the reference of the case object like the following. "mypackage.Cowboy$Good$" = cowboySerializer

Comment: If I add '$' sign at the end of class name, same exception occurs (ActorInitializationException -> InvocationTargetException -> ClassNotFoundException). The only change is that now it can't find mypackage.Cowboy$Good$ instead of mypackage.Cowboy$Good